# ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from 'aws_cdk'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, import, aws-cdk

I'm trying to make a very basic Lambda function using AWS CDK and This is what I"ve got so far

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as apigw,
    core,
)


class SportsTeamGeneratorStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
                code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda",
                    bundling= core.BundlingOptions(
                        image=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                        command=[
                            "bash", "-c",
                            "pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output"
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )

        apigw.LambdaRestApi(
            self, 'Endpoint',
            handler=my_lambda,
        )
```

Although I'm getting the following error: ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from 'aws_cdk'. I'm setting up my lambda this way because I'm trying to include external packages using python in the actual code, and want those files to be zipped up and given to s3. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using Python - why not implement your Lambda function using Python?

Comment: I am implementing the lambda using python, this is just the cdk construct that is generating the lambda in the stack

Comment: that makes sense.

Comment: I will check internally to see if anyone has an idea on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`core` is not a module in `aws_cdk`.

You can import the core package as `core` using the following code:

`import aws_cdk as core`